# How to transfer Google Earth route to Google Maps?

Tags: routing, google-maps, google-earth

I have a GPX route, I imported it into Google Earth. Everything is fine, so I saved it as KMZ file. Then just for check, I imported KMZ back into Google Earth. No problem.

The thing is, I would like to work with Google Maps, no Google Earth and I am not able to transfer this route into Google Maps. Each time I select "show in Google Maps", the view is switched from Earth to Maps, but my route is missing.

If I use standalone web browser and try to import any of the files directly to Google Maps, either it falls into some infinite loop (I wait ~hour and still see progress bar) or Google Maps shows error. It seems direct update is simply broken.

(**New paragraph**) More reliable way to import a file is to upload it first to some website, and then using URL of uploaded file, import it (by giving URL) to Google Maps. As for transfer, it works, however Google Maps shows just the beginning of the route (around 25%).

Thus the question: **how to transfer a route from Google Earth to Google Maps?**

*KMZ file size is 300KB, KML (unpacked) file is 800KB.*

Answer (score 1):

Finally!

Starting from GPX file, grab your Android phone, install My Tracks. Upload your file into `/mnt/scard/MyTracks/gpx` at the phone. Then run MyTracks and import the file (lengthy process). Then upload it again this time from MyTracks app into Google Maps.

Phew ;-)

If anyone has a better reliable solution, please post an answer.